# I need to automate write-log for this function

Tags: function, powershell, logging, parameters

I have got the following function write-log, and I would like to put the logs generate when running the script in a sub-folder and rename them file.logs.old. Moreover, I would like to keep the last log in the script folder. Example

LAST LOG:

```
C:\scripts\powershellscript\logs.log
```

SUB-FOLDER OLD LOGS:

```
C:\scripts\powershellscript\logfolder\
```

OLD LOGS:

```
C:\scripts\powershellscript\logfolder\logs1.log.old
C:\scripts\powershellscript\logfolder\logs2.log.old
C:\scripts\powershellscript\logfolder\logs3.log.old
Etc...
```

I have the following function, but it only saves the last log and overrides it:

```
function write-Log
{
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        #Message
        $Message,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        #Errormessage
        $ErrorMessage,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        #Component that create the error
        $Component,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        #Error Type
        [int]$Type,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        #Filepath to the Logfile
        $LogFile
    )

    #Create a Timestamp
    $Date = Get-Date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy"
    $time = Get-Date -Format "HH:mm:ss.fff"

    #If you type a error message the type will automatically switch to type 3 Error
    if ($null -ne $ErrorMessage)
    { $Type = 3
    }
    #If you type no Component the Component will set to space
    if ($null -eq $Component)
    { $Component = " "
    }
    #If you set the type variable it is set to 1 automatically
    if ($null -eq $Type)
    { $Type = 1
    }

    #create the log entry
    $LogMessage = "<![LOG[$Message  $ErrorMessage ]LOG]!>" + "<time=`"$time`" date=`"$Date`" component=`"$Component`" context=`"`" type=`"$Type`" thread=`"`" file=`"`">"
    #write the log entry
    $LogMessage | Out-File -Append -Encoding UTF8 -FilePath $LogFile

}
```

this is the current variable to store the log

```
#Variable
$Logfile = "C:\Scripts\powershellscript\logs.log" #logfile path
```

How can I achieve that? I am Looking for help for this function that needs to be added to the user's query. The script is working but only append the last log. And long-term is no going to be manageable for checking old logs.

Thanks

Comment: [1] write & test the code to do what you want. [2] convert it into a function. [3] add that func to the beginning of your script. [4] call it before OR in the `Write-Log` function to handle that process.

Comment: Hi @Lee_Dailey, thank you for your answer. I got already a working script but it only keeps and saves one log file. What I am looking for is to automate the log creation in the function so that I have the last log file saved in the script folder and the old log files moved in the subfolder for archiving. Is there any way I can expand further the function I have added in the post for this scope? As of know all the steps you mentioned 1,2,3,4 are working but save only one log file.

Comment: i was referring to the _additional_ function to be added to your presented code. [*grin*] i would [A] check for the size or date of the existing file before writing to it. [B] rename the file with a timestamp if it is too large/old. ///// another solution would be to simply create a new file every day. something like - 'is file from today? use it! if not from today, make new one with todays date` - seems to cover the idea ... and it is both simple and fairly robust.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, appreciate your input on this. I posted something that for me works fine for now. Regards, StackLad

Comment: that is what i was thinking of, too! glad to see that you got it working for you as needed! [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might find usefull this module - https://github.com/PoShLog/PoShLog

Install it with `Install-Module PoShLog`

Then you can setup new file logger like this:

```
Import-Module PoShLog

# Setup new logger
New-Logger |
    Set-MinimumLevel -Value Verbose |
    Add-SinkFile -Path 'C:\Scripts\Logs\Script-.log' -RollingInterval Minute  | # Add logging into file
    Start-Logger

# Try some logging methods
Write-InfoLog 'Some information to be logged...'

try {
    ConvertFrom-Json 'xxx'
}
catch {
    Write-ErrorLog 'Error occured!' -ErrorRecord $_
}

Close-Logger
```

[image: poshlog-filesink-dir]

This will create new log file every minute, but you can change the interval with parameter [`RollingInterval`](https://github.com/PoShLog/PoShLog/wiki/Add-SinkFile#-rollinginterval), you can also limit file count in your log directory or file size, more information [here in wiki](https://github.com/PoShLog/PoShLog/wiki/Add-SinkFile). In example above I've shown only two log methods, but there are [6 in total](https://github.com/PoShLog/PoShLog/wiki/Write-Cmdlets).

I hope this is helpful, if you have any questions, look at [PoShLog wiki](https://github.com/PoShLog/PoShLog/wiki) or reach me at [discord](https://discord.gg/FVdVxuw). Happy coding!

Comment: This is an excellent option though it not quite straightforward and need developer/community support to get it rolling.

Answer (score 0):

Which logs do you want to move? The one you have just created or the ones created before?

To move a file you can use the `mv` command.

```
mv log old_log_folder/old_log
```

Maybe I did not understand your request.
Best,

Comment: I am building a script and for the future use, I would like to move the "old log file" to this folder and keep only the last one in the script folder. This needs to be added in the function so that it completes the process during the script. I have updated the post. I am not looking to do this manually but to build it in the function.

Answer (score 0):

That solution worked for me and as of now I am keeping this:

```
#Variable
#Add date to the log file name and date
$day = Get-Date -Format dd
$month = Get-Date -Format MM
$year = Get-Date -Format yyyy
$hour = Get-Date -Format HH
$minute = Get-Date -Format mm
$hoy = "$day" + "$month" + "$year" + "$hour" + "$minute"
New-Item C:\Scripts\Logs\Script-$hoy.log -type file -force
#Add end date
```

In that way, with timestamp and force new item I always have a new log file in the logs folder created manually.

A better solution is still appreciated though. :)